# VisualGDB and Raspberry pi

Tags: c++, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

When using this turotial: http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/raspberry/crosscompiler/.

I built the solution in Visual Studio 2012, and I got this output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: LinuxHelloWorld, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  VisualGDB: Attempting inline build...
1>  VisualGDB: Run "cmd.exe /c "C:\SysGCC\raspberry\bin\make.exe" CONFIG=Debug" in directory "C:\Users\Kels\LinuxHelloWorld\LinuxHelloWorld" on local computer
1>  make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
1>  -------------------------------------------------------------
1>  Command exited with code 2
1>  Executable: cmd.exe
1>  Arguments: /c "C:\SysGCC\raspberry\bin\make.exe" CONFIG=Debug
1>  Directory: C:\Users\Kels\LinuxHelloWorld\LinuxHelloWorld
1>VisualGDB : error : Command-line action failed
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(38,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Sysprogs\VisualGDB\VisualGDB.exe" /build "C:\Users\Kels\LinuxHelloWorld\LinuxHelloWorld\LinuxHelloWorld.vcxproj" "/solution:C:\Users\Kels\LinuxHelloWorld\LinuxHelloWorld.sln" "/config:Debug" "/platform:Win32"" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I am confused on what the next step would be for the command-line failure.
Thanks ahead of time!!

Added 10/20. The Makefile in C:\Users\Kels\LinuxHelloWorld\LinuxHelloWorld

```
#Generated by VisualGDB project wizard. 
#Note: VisualGDB will automatically update this file when you add new sources to the project.
#All other changes you make in this file will be preserved.
#Visit http://visualgdb.com/makefiles for more details

#VisualGDB: AutoSourceFiles     #<--- remove this line to disable auto-updating of SOURCEFILES and EXTERNAL_LIBS

TARGETNAME := LinuxHelloWorld
#TARGETTYPE can be APP, STATIC or SHARED
TARGETTYPE := APP

to_lowercase = $(subst A,a,$(subst B,b,$(subst C,c,$(subst D,d,$(subst E,e,$(subst F,f,$(subst G,g,$(subst H,h,$(subst I,i,$(subst J,j,$(subst K,k,$(subst L,l,$(subst M,m,$(subst N,n,$(subst O,o,$(subst P,p,$(subst Q,q,$(subst R,r,$(subst S,s,$(subst T,t,$(subst U,u,$(subst V,v,$(subst W,w,$(subst X,x,$(subst Y,y,$(subst Z,z,$1))))))))))))))))))))))))))

CONFIG ?= DEBUG

CONFIGURATION_FLAGS_FILE := $(call to_lowercase,$(CONFIG)).mak

    include $(CONFIGURATION_FLAGS_FILE)
include $(ADDITIONAL_MAKE_FILES)

ifeq ($(BINARYDIR),)
error:
    $(error Invalid configuration, please check your inputs)
endif

SOURCEFILES := LinuxHelloWorld.cpp
EXTERNAL_LIBS := 
EXTERNAL_LIBS_COPIED := $(foreach lib, $(EXTERNAL_LIBS),$(BINARYDIR)/$(notdir $(lib)))

CFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
ASFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
LDFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)

CFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS))
CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS))

CFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))
CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))
ASFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))

CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(MACOS_FRAMEWORKS))
CFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(MACOS_FRAMEWORKS))
LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(MACOS_FRAMEWORKS))

LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -L,$(LIBRARY_DIRS))

ifeq ($(GENERATE_MAP_FILE),1)
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-Map=$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).map
endif

LIBRARY_LDFLAGS = $(addprefix -l,$(LIBRARY_NAMES))

ifeq ($(IS_LINUX_PROJECT),1)
    RPATH_PREFIX := -Wl,--rpath='$$ORIGIN/../
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath='$$ORIGIN'
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(addsuffix ',$(addprefix $(RPATH_PREFIX),$(dir $(EXTERNAL_LIBS))))

    ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),SHARED)
        CFLAGS += -fPIC
        CXXFLAGS += -fPIC
        ASFLAGS += -fPIC
        LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += -Wl,-soname,$(TARGETNAME)
    endif

    ifneq ($(LINUX_PACKAGES),)
        PACKAGE_CFLAGS := $(foreach pkg,$(LINUX_PACKAGES),$(shell pkg-config --cflags $(pkg)))
        PACKAGE_LDFLAGS := $(foreach pkg,$(LINUX_PACKAGES),$(shell pkg-config --libs $(pkg)))
        CFLAGS += $(PACKAGE_CFLAGS)
        CXXFLAGS += $(PACKAGE_CFLAGS)
        LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(PACKAGE_LDFLAGS)
    endif   
else
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
endif

LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(ADDITIONAL_LINKER_INPUTS)

all_make_files := $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) $(CONFIGURATION_FLAGS_FILE) $(ADDITIONAL_MAKE_FILES)

ifeq ($(STARTUPFILES),)
    all_source_files := $(SOURCEFILES)
else
    all_source_files := $(STARTUPFILES) $(filter-out $(STARTUPFILES),$(SOURCEFILES))
endif

source_obj1 := $(all_source_files:.cpp=.o)
source_obj2 := $(source_obj1:.c=.o)
source_obj3 := $(source_obj2:.s=.o)
source_obj4 := $(source_obj3:.S=.o)
source_obj5 := $(source_obj4:.cc=.o)
source_objs := $(source_obj5:.cxx=.o)

all_objs := $(addprefix $(BINARYDIR)/, $(notdir $(source_objs)))

PRIMARY_OUTPUTS :=

ifeq ($(GENERATE_BIN_FILE),1)
PRIMARY_OUTPUTS += $(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin
endif

ifeq ($(GENERATE_IHEX_FILE),1)
PRIMARY_OUTPUTS += $(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).ihex
endif

ifeq ($(PRIMARY_OUTPUTS),)
PRIMARY_OUTPUTS := $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
endif

all: $(PRIMARY_OUTPUTS)

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).ihex: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O ihex $< $@

ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),APP)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) $(all_objs) $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),SHARED)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
    $(LD) -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) $(all_objs) $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),STATIC)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs)
    $(AR) -r $@ $^
endif

-include $(all_objs:.o=.dep)

clean:
ifeq ($(USE_DEL_TO_CLEAN),1)
    del /S /Q $(BINARYDIR)
else
    rm -rf $(BINARYDIR)
endif

$(BINARYDIR):
    mkdir $(BINARYDIR)

#VisualGDB: FileSpecificTemplates       #<--- VisualGDB will use the following lines to define rules for source files in subdirectories
$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.cpp $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.c $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.S $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.s $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.cc $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.cxx $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

#VisualGDB: GeneratedRules  

        #<--- All lines below are auto-generated
```

Comment: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

Comment: Okay, so how to I fix that.
I went into C:\SysGCC\raspberry\bin\ and there is a make.exe. But when I run it from the command line I get the error: make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Comment: Realistically, the people most likely to be able to help you with this *rather odd combination of microsoft and open-source* are the creators of the tutorial you are following.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm also using VisualGDB for Raspberry Pi development, one of the greatest plugins I've seen. From your log it seems that you are using a cross compilation toolchain to make build. 
First thing you can do is go to the `C:\Users\Kels\LinuxHelloWorld\LinuxHelloWorld` and verify the existence of a `Makefile` there and check the contents (maybe even add them to the question there so they can be expected). Another option is to set up compilation on the Pi itself instead of the using a toolchain (this can be done through the project wizard) - it will be slower since Pi cannot be compared to a PC, but then again, any 3rd party libraries which you may need (and most likely you will) can be easily installed on the Pi via `apt-get` and just used while you will have to cross compile them on your PC if you use the toolchain.

**UPDATE**

Heres is an example Makefile of one of my sample projects:

```
#Generated by VisualGDB project wizard. 
#Note: VisualGDB will automatically update this file when you add new sources to the project.
#All other changes you make in this file will be preserved.
#Visit http://visualgdb.com/makefiles for more details

#VisualGDB: AutoSourceFiles     #<--- remove this line to disable auto-updating of SOURCEFILES and EXTERNAL_LIBS

TARGETNAME := RpiOmxTunnelReconfiguration
#TARGETTYPE can be APP, STATIC or SHARED
TARGETTYPE := APP

to_lowercase = $(subst A,a,$(subst B,b,$(subst C,c,$(subst D,d,$(subst E,e,$(subst F,f,$(subst G,g,$(subst H,h,$(subst I,i,$(subst J,j,$(subst K,k,$(subst L,l,$(subst M,m,$(subst N,n,$(subst O,o,$(subst P,p,$(subst Q,q,$(subst R,r,$(subst S,s,$(subst T,t,$(subst U,u,$(subst V,v,$(subst W,w,$(subst X,x,$(subst Y,y,$(subst Z,z,$1))))))))))))))))))))))))))

CONFIG ?= DEBUG

CONFIGURATION_FLAGS_FILE := $(call to_lowercase,$(CONFIG)).mak

include $(CONFIGURATION_FLAGS_FILE)
include $(ADDITIONAL_MAKE_FILES)

ifeq ($(BINARYDIR),)
error:
    $(error Invalid configuration, please check your inputs)
endif

SOURCEFILES := Omx/Component.cpp Omx/ComponentPort.cpp RpiOmxTunnelReconfiguration.cpp
EXTERNAL_LIBS := 
EXTERNAL_LIBS_COPIED := $(foreach lib, $(EXTERNAL_LIBS),$(BINARYDIR)/$(notdir $(lib)))

CFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
CXXFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
ASFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)
LDFLAGS += $(COMMONFLAGS)

CFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS))
CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -I,$(INCLUDE_DIRS))

CFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))
CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))
ASFLAGS += $(addprefix -D,$(PREPROCESSOR_MACROS))

CXXFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(MACOS_FRAMEWORKS))
CFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(MACOS_FRAMEWORKS))
LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -framework ,$(MACOS_FRAMEWORKS))

LDFLAGS += $(addprefix -L,$(LIBRARY_DIRS))

LIBRARY_LDFLAGS = $(addprefix -l,$(LIBRARY_NAMES))

ifeq ($(IS_LINUX_PROJECT),1)
    RPATH_PREFIX := -Wl,--rpath='$$ORIGIN/../
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += -Wl,--rpath='$$ORIGIN'
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(addsuffix ',$(addprefix $(RPATH_PREFIX),$(dir $(EXTERNAL_LIBS))))

    ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),SHARED)
        LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += -Wl,-soname,$(TARGETNAME)
    endif

else
    LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
endif

LIBRARY_LDFLAGS += $(ADDITIONAL_LINKER_INPUTS)

all_make_files := Makefile $(CONFIGURATION_FLAGS_FILE) $(ADDITIONAL_MAKE_FILES)

ifeq ($(STARTUPFILES),)
    all_source_files := $(SOURCEFILES)
else
    all_source_files := $(STARTUPFILES) $(filter-out $(STARTUPFILES),$(SOURCEFILES))
endif

source_obj1 := $(all_source_files:.cpp=.o)
source_obj2 := $(source_obj1:.c=.o)
source_obj3 := $(source_obj2:.s=.o)
source_objs := $(source_obj3:.S=.o)

all_objs := $(addprefix $(BINARYDIR)/, $(notdir $(source_objs)))

ifeq ($(GENERATE_BIN_FILE),1)
all: $(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

else
all: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),APP)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
    $(LD) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) $(all_objs) $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),SHARED)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs) $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
    $(LD) -shared -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $(START_GROUP) $(all_objs) $(LIBRARY_LDFLAGS) $(END_GROUP)
endif

ifeq ($(TARGETTYPE),STATIC)
$(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME): $(all_objs)
    $(AR) -r $@ $^
endif

-include $(all_objs:.o=.dep)

clean:
ifeq ($(USE_DEL_TO_CLEAN),1)
    del /S /Q $(BINARYDIR)
else
    rm -rf $(BINARYDIR)
endif

$(BINARYDIR):
    mkdir $(BINARYDIR)

#VisualGDB: FileSpecificTemplates       #<--- VisualGDB will use the following lines to define rules for source files in subdirectories
$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.cpp $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.c $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.S $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

$(BINARYDIR)/%.o : %.s $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(ASFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)

#VisualGDB: GeneratedRules              #<--- All lines below are auto-generated


$(BINARYDIR)/Component.o : Omx/Component.cpp $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)


$(BINARYDIR)/ComponentPort.o : Omx/ComponentPort.cpp $(all_make_files) |$(BINARYDIR)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c $< -o $@ -MD -MF $(@:.o=.dep)
```

As you see here `TARGETNAME := RpiOmxTunnelReconfiguration` and

```
ifeq ($(GENERATE_BIN_FILE),1)
all: $(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin

$(BINARYDIR)/$(basename $(TARGETNAME)).bin: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
    $(OBJCOPY) -O binary $< $@

else
all: $(BINARYDIR)/$(TARGETNAME)
endif
```

will always define an output binary file. Maybe recreate the project.

Comment: I was able to find a Makefile in the folder. I added it to the question above. Would you suggest setting up the compilation on the Pi verses the tool chain? This is my first experience using Pi, so I am learning as I go. Thank you!

Comment: If the projects are small and dont require a great amount of time to compile I think it makes sense to perform the compilation directly on the Pi.

Comment: As for the make file - it looks a bit weird, the `PRIMARY_OUTPUTS` could end up empty and then target `all` would have no dependencies, check the project settings. I looked at one sample project of mine, and there the output file was defined, so it could be that the project settings are simply wrong.

Comment: In the project settings, what should I be looking for that may cause the weird make file?

Comment: And the projects are small so I'll look into performing the compilation on the Pi as well. Thanks so much for the help!